# What happens when a method is overridden in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

When a predefined method in Java is overridden...

1. Only the method signature must be same
2. Both method signature and inheritance must be same

What is the answer?  1  or  2

I know that when we override the method in superclass, the method signature should be the same.  But what about the inheritance? I have read this question in a book, but I did not find any answer even after some research.

Comment: `both method signature and inheritance must be same` explain that please.

Comment: [Overriding and Hiding Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html)

Comment: @Saif  i read that in a book. i too got the same doubt. if you have any idea post your anwer

Comment: Either you're translating it wrong, you're misquoting, or the author doesn't know what they are talking about. In any case, clarify with a quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html):

> An instance method in a subclass with the same signature (name, plus the number and the type of its parameters) and return type as an instance method in the superclass overrides the superclass's method.

**The method signature must be the same; that is, the name, parameters, position of parameters, and number of parameters must match.**

The most common example of this is `toString()`, which lives on `Object`.  `Object`'s `toString` method is defined as this:

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

...whereas `AbstractCollection`*'s `toString` method is defined as this:

```
public String toString() {
    Iterator<E> it = iterator();
    if (! it.hasNext())
        return "[]";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append('[');
    for (;;) {
        E e = it.next();
        sb.append(e == this ? "(this Collection)" : e);
        if (! it.hasNext())
            return sb.append(']').toString();
        sb.append(',').append(' ');
    }
}
```

Notice that both of the method signatures are the same, but what they return is different.  This is the intention of overriding; your parent class has defined specific behavior for it that doesn't necessarily make sense in the children classes, so one simply overtakes that behavior and makes it suitable for the child class.

<sup>*:  This is used for anything that is an `AbstractCollection`, like `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`.</sup>

---

To expand a bit:  the visibility of the method in the child also plays a role.

From this [handy chart](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html), methods that have the `private` modifier cannot be passed to subclasses.

When overriding methods, you cannot reduce the visibility of a method; that is, you cannot descend lower in the visibility order provided.

To help, here's a quick list.

If the method in your parent is...

- `public`:  the subclass' override **must** be `public`.
- `protected`:  the subclass' override can either be `public` or `protected`.
- `<no modifier>` or package-private:  the subclass' override can be `public`, `protected`, or package-private.
- `private`:  the subclass doesn't even know the method *exists*.

Comment: i think here inheritance may be referring to access specifier mentioned in the predefined superclass. If we extend that class and try to override the method, we are not allowed to increase the access by placing the public access specifier (let superclass method have private).  Is inheritance word in this context referring to it? If it is the case my problem is clarified!

Comment: I think you're getting visibility conflated in here, but I'll amend my answer.